# CSS formatting of multiple nav groups

Tags: css

Given mark-up similar to:

```
<h1 id="Menu1Title">Menu1</h1>
<nav id="Menu1">
    <a>Item1-1</a>
    <a>Item1-2</a>
    <a>Item1-3</a>
</nav>

<h1 id="Menu2Title">Menu2</h1>
<nav id="Menu2">
    <a>Item2-1</a>
    <a>Item2-2</a>
    <a>Item2-3</a>
</nav>

<h1 id="Menu3Title">Menu3</h1>
<nav id="Menu3">
    <a>Item3-1</a>
    <a>Item3-2</a>
    <a>Item3-3</a>
</nav>
```

How can this presentation be achieved using CSS only?

```
Menu1  Menu2  Menu3
Item1-1
Item1-2
Item1-3
Item2-1
Item2-2
Item2-3
Item3-1
Item3-2
Item3-3
```

ULs can also be used as long as they are three separate elements and not sub-lists of one another.  I'd prefer not to use absolute positioning as there is other content below this that should flow around the mark-up above.  I also have no need for old IE hacks; only supporting IE9 and modern browsers.

Is this even possible? Thanks!

Edit... The above formatting question is to style for mobile.  Non-mobile is displayed as below which is why I was hoping for a CSS-only solution that didn't require mark-up changes.

```
Menu1
Item1-1 
Item1-2 
Item1-3 

Menu2
Item2-1 
Item2-2 
Item2-3 

Menu3 
Item3-1 
Item3-2 
Item3-3
```

Comment: using jquery or javascript it can be easily achieved, why don u try jquery?

Comment: Yes, I could easily do it in jQuery but I'm hoping someone can provide a CSS solution.  I try to use jQuery for behavior and CSS for presentation.  Makes for a cleaner separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

OK, if you really cant change mark up or use jQuery to alter the mark up then below is a CSS only solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/wSLEb/

You could absolutely position the headers and give the first ul margin top. Then using `:nth-of-type` pseudo class selector you could target individual headers and give them more left positioning to push them across the page and away from one another.

It's not very flexible as you have to hard code the left positioning so take into account how the width of the headers are rendered on a mobile screen.

Mark up would be:

```
<h1 id="Menu1Title" class="header">Menu1</h1>
<nav id="Menu1">
<ul class="first">
<li><a>Item1-1</a></li>
<li><a>Item1-2</a></li>
<li><a>Item1-3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<h1 id="Menu2Title" class="header">Menu2</h1>
<nav id="Menu2">
<ul>
<li><a>Item2-1</a></li>
<li><a>Item2-2</a></li>
<li><a>Item2-3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<h1 id="Menu3Title" class="header">Menu3</h1>
<nav id="Menu3">
<ul>
<li><a>Item3-1</a></li>
<li><a>Item3-2</a></li>
<li><a>Item3-3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

and CSS would be:

```
.header {
   position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
.header:nth-of-type(2) {
    left:50px;
}
.header:nth-of-type(3) {
    left:100px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul.first {
 margin-top: 20px;
}
```

You can read more about pseudo class selectors on Chris Coyier's site here: http://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

To start your lists should be in uls.

if you can't use absolute positioning then you need to change your mark up to achieve that kind of styling. The headers should appear after one another in the html. If you can't change your mark up at the source then you will have to use jQuery to reorder the mark up on page load.

in your jQuery I would target all of the headers and then remove all of them except for the first and then insert these removed headers after the first one, and then place a clearing div after the last header.

See this or the code below: http://jsfiddle.net/wSLEb/

Your mark up would become like so:

```
<h1 id="Menu1Title" class="header">Menu1</h1>
<h1 id="Menu2Title" class="header">Menu2</h1>
<h1 id="Menu3Title" class="header">Menu3</h1>
<div class="clear"></div> <!--clearing div added to move first ul under the headers-->
<nav id="Menu1">
<ul>

<li><a>Item1-1</a></li>
<li><a>Item1-2</a></li>
<li><a>Item1-3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<nav id="Menu2">
<ul>
<li><a>Item2-1</a></li>
<li><a>Item2-2</a></li>
<li><a>Item2-3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<nav id="Menu3">
<ul>
<li><a>Item3-1</a></li>
<li><a>Item3-2</a></li>
<li><a>Item3-3</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

The styling would then be like so:

```
.header {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dave.  Perhaps it's just not possible without script or markup changes.  Dang.